# Warning: Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted with "UISeachController"

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

To visualize - I've got the main view controller embedded in a `UINavigationController` and on this view controller the `UISearchController` is installed. After performing the search tapping a row on the table view containing the search results, it segues the user to the next view controller. Then on pressing the back button I get this warning. This doesn't happen on the iPad, only iPhone. The bigger picture is that the `UINavigationController` is the detail view controller of a `UISplitViewController`.

This is the implementation of the `UISearchController`

```
    func initializeSearchController() {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        writersTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Favorites"]
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search writers"

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.delegate = self

        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true

        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.loadViewIfNeeded()
    }
```

Then there is another thing. I set the title of the second view controller dynamically according to which search result row is tapped like this: `title = writer.name` - The back button gets reset to whatever the value of the title of the second view controller is - and the title 'in the middle of the navigation bar' is left out blank.
What I would like to have is the back button as it is and the second view controller title changes dynamically.

As indicated this doesn't happen with the iPad - Only iPhone?

Comment: Can you show your code for the view controller that contains the search controller?

Comment: Try and embed UISearchController in a UISearchContainerViewController